# Improve JS Regex pattern for name validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to create a regex pattern for name validation.
Application name must have the following:

1. Lowercase alphanumeric characters can be specified
2. Name must start with an alphabetic character and can end with alphanumeric character
3. Hyphen '-' is allowed but not as the first or last character
   **e.g abc123, abc, abcd-1232**

This is what I got `[^\[a-z\]+(\[a-z0-9\-\])*\[a-z0-9\]$][1]` it doesn't work perfectly. The validation fails if you enter a single character in the field. How can I improve this pattern? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^[a-z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

Explanation:

- `^[a-z]` starts with lowercase alpha
- `(?:` turn off capture group

  - `[a-z0-9-]*` zero or more alphanumeric OR dash
  - `[a-z0-9]` mandatory end in alphanumeric only, if length > 1
- `)?` make this group optional
- `$` end of input

Answer (score 0):

You are using a negated character class `[^` that matches 1 character, not being any of the specified characters in the character class.

That is followed by another character class `[1]` which can only match `1`, so the pattern matches 2 characters, like for example `#1`

---

In your examples you seem to have only a single hyphen, so if there can not be consecutive hyphens `--`

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
- `[a-z0-9]*` Optionally repeat any of a-z or 0-9
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `-` followed by at least 1 or a-z or 0-9 (So there can not be a hyphen at the end)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gfQQHt/1)